# how to get sum of amount by checking that partyname same as in another table

Tags: mysql

I am working on a project where there are 2 tables first TABLENAME>**SALES** has :
**Partyname** and **Totalamount**
and second, TABLENAME>**CASH** has **Partyname** and **Amountrecevied**

SALES has 2 entries as

*Partyname    Totalamount*

> Restaurant Teliabagh  80000
>
> Restaurant Teliabagh  20000

and CASH has 2 entries as

*Partyname Amountrecevied*

> Restaurant Teliabagh  20000
>
> Restaurant Teliabagh  20000

ON trying this Command

```
SELECT sum(totalamount) 
from acc.sales s, acc.cash c 
where s.Partyname=c.Party_name;
```

the output  i am getting is

> '200000'

here the output is getting double

Comment: And what's your question about this? What's the expected output? What have you tried to resolve your problem?

Comment: the output I want is 100000 is the following output is amount is getting doubled so is there any way to get that output

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question, along with more details

Comment: i have mistakenly pressed enter after that i did not no how to edit the question again.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to check that `Partyname` is in the `cash` table, this should work:

```
select sum(Totalamount)
from sales
where Partyname in (select Partyname from cash);
```

Comment: You don't need the `where Partyname in (select Partyname from cash)` condition. Just `select sum(Totalamount) from sales` will do